# Re render when data from async function is ready

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have an async function that GET the notes from network, the problem that I have is that it tries to render an empty array of data, therefore I get this error saying that item.id is `undefined` because the array is empty. I tried to put a condition `if (data.length === 0) return <Text>No Entries</Text>` but then it does not re render anything, even though when I `console.log(data)` I can see the data has arrived. Is there any way to re render when data has arrived, or any other way around this?

```
export default class NoteList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data} = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={styles.cardView}>
        <FlatList
          numColons={data.length}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item: { name, content, id } }) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <NoteCard 
                  name={name}
                  content={content}
                />
              </View>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How to prevent this:

```
TypeError: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')
```

I also get this error, but I think it is related to the management of the first problem.

```
Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory 
leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, the componentWillUnmount method,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have, lies in the parent where data is saved in the state. Therefor you get the warning about updating the state of an unmounted component. There are a lot of different ways to fix this. One way I like (because of the readability), is using a variable for when the component mounts. A simple example:

```
class News extends Component {
  _isMounted = false;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      news: [],
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    axios
      .get('https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search?query=react')
      .then(result => {
        if (this._isMounted) {
          this.setState({
            news: result.data.hits,
          });
        }
      });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._isMounted = false;
  }
  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now when the data is set, the NoteList component will automatically get updated. However what happens when api call fails. To prevent stale data, I like to use conditional rendering. Just like you suggested:

```
export default class NoteList extends Component {
  render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    if (data) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.cardView}>
          <FlatList
            numColons={data.length}
            data={data}
            renderItem={({ item: { name, content, id } }) => {
              return (
                <View>
                  <NoteCard name={name} content={content} />
                </View>
              );
            }}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i save the state to AsyncStorage and I want to get these data from asyncStorage to render it in the same screen (I don't render it via the state) but it's not rendering immediately how can I solve it?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if I understand, so correct me if I'm wrong. You fetch the data on a specific screen, then you want to save it in AsyncStorage so you can display it on the same screen?

Comment: You should await the result (because its async storage), in a lifecyle method like `componentDidMount()` or with the useEffect hook `useEffect(()=>{},[])`. Because the fetch from the AsyncStorage can fail, I'd save the data in state after you received it from AsyncStorage and render it conditionally like I did above. `if(data) return ...`

Comment: Hmm u right, the main reasons I have 2 screens first one I ask the user to choose something and after that, I save it in state and asyncStorage then, navigate to the second screen and get data from the server based on this choice and it takes time to get the data

Comment: Depending on the navigation library you're using (I'd suggest using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/)), you can easily pass the data from one screen to another. So it would be faster to fetch all data once then separately on each screen.

Comment: Ouch, I already use React Navigation but forget to use it, thank u Jurrian

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this in React is to keep track of when data is being fetched. This can be done e.g. by having a isFetching field in your state:

```
// This would be your default state
this.state = {
  isFetching: false
};
```

Then, when you fire off the request (preferably in componentDidMount) you set isFetching to true using:

```
this.setState({ isFetching: true });
```

And finally, when the data arrives, you set it to false again:

```
this.setState({ isFetching: false });
```

Now, in your render function you can do something like this:

```
render () {
 return (
    <div className="something">
      <h3>Some content</h3>
      {this.state.isFetching ? <LoadingComponent /> : (
         <ul>
           {listItems}
         </ul>
      )}
    </div> 
  )
}
```

By using state, you don't have to worry about telling your component to do something, instead it reacts to changes in the state and renders it accordingly.